# F# Map Trouble

Tags: f#

I am having trouble groking F#'s Map class. I created a simple, naive lambda calculus evaluation function,

```
type Name = string
type Term =
    |   Var of Name 
    |   Lit of int
    |   App of Term * Term
    |   Lam of Name * Term

let rec lookup(v, e) =
    match e with
    |   (v1, t)::tl         -> if v1 = v then t else lookup(v, tl)
    |   []                  -> failwith "unknown variable %s" v

let rec eval(x, e) = 
    match x with
    |   Var x               -> lookup(x, e)
    |   Lit x               -> Lit x
    |   App (Lam(v, f), t2) -> eval(f, ((v, t2)::e))
    |   _                   -> failwith "Invalid"
```

The obvious optimization to this is to change the list to a Map so I came up with,

```
let rec eval2(x, e: Map<Name,Term>) =
    match x with
    |   Var v               -> e.[v]
    |   Lit l               -> x
    |   App (Lam (v, f), t) -> eval2(f, e.Add(v, t))
    |   _                   -> failwith "Invalid term"
```

Given the values,

```
let ident = Lam ("x", Var "x")
let prog = App (ident, Lit 3)
```

why does,

```
let x = eval(prog, [])
```

succeed but,

```
let x2 = eval2(prog, Map [])
```

throw a key not found exception?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't repro this behavior (using F# 1.9.6.2, it works for me):

```
#light

type Name = string
type Term =
    |   Var of Name
    |   Lit of int
    |   App of Term * Term
    |   Lam of Name * Term

let rec eval2(x, e: Map<Name,Term>) =
    match x with
    |   Var v               -> e.[v]
    |   Lit l               -> x
    |   App (Lam (v, f), t) -> eval2(f, e.Add(v, t))
    |   _                   -> failwith "Invalid term"

let ident = Lam ("x", Var "x")
let prog = App (ident, Lit 3)
let x2 = eval2(prog, Map [])
printfn "%A" x2   // Lit 3
```

Comment: Hmm. Now, after closing and reopening VS, I cannot reproduce it either.